# Call finish() on activity in one hour

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an activity that calls `super.finish()` an hour after it was started. Currently I'm using `new Handler().postDelayed(...)` but it's failing when the device is asleep (I've read that it makes the timer pause).

This is my current code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...
    // some irrelevant code here
    // ...

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
}
```

I thought of using `AlarmManager` to schedule the operation, but I understood that `finish()` can be called only from UI thread.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've stumbled upon this answer before, but from further reading it seems that `timer.schedule` is no good as it executes the action on a background thread, whereas `finish()` - to my understanding - needs to be called from the UI thread (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might come across the same problem -

I ended up using `AlarmManager` as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...
    // some irrelevant code here
    // ...

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("finish.goodhour.activity"));
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(),
            (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),
            new Intent().setAction("finish.goodhour.activity"),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60,
            pendingIntent);
}
```

Note that the `BroadcastReceiver` registered to the same `IntentFilter` as the intent in the alarm ("finish.goodhour.activity").

Answer (score 0):

```
 new CountDownTimer(1000*60*60, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {

            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
        }.start();
```